# Initializing string variables from mapping values doesnt work

Tags: solidity, mapping, string

I try something like this:

```
mapping (uint256 =>string) public example;
```

then i initialze 'example' in the constructor

```
example[0]="apple";
example[1]="peach";
```

then i define a variable like this

```
string fruit=example[1];
```

However: "fruit" never receives any value while 'example' is successfully initialized.
(deploying works fine - the compiler (remix) doesnt show any error. I checked the spelling of everything like 10x)

Please help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you declare a local variable you should use `memory`, example with hardhat log:

```csharp
import "hardhat/console.sol";

contract Foo {
    mapping (uint256 => string) public example;

    constructor () {
        example[0] = "apple";
        example[1] = "peach";
    }

    function foo () external {
        string memory fruit = example[1];
        console.log("Fruit is:", fruit);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its due to how solidity's compiler solves the instructions, `fruit` is a state variable so when you initialize it the value of `example[1]` is empty because the constructor gets called after the initialization of state variables. To solve this you can define the fruit as state variable and initialize it in the constructor, example:

```
mapping (uint256 =>string) public example;
    string fruit;

    constructor(){
        example[0]="apple";
        example[1]="peach";
        fruit = example[1];
    }
```

This way fruit is initialized correctly.
Please accept and upvote if it helps